# Asp.net MVC, Razor & Entity Framework: Childobject lost id/relation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm using a form to get some data from the user. The current userdata are loaded to the form as readonly fields and some other fields for user input.
My model looks like this:

```
Mainobject
-Field1
-Field2
...
-Userdataobject
    -Name
    -Street
...
```

The textfields in the form are bound to the model. The userdata are loaded from the database

```
Userdataobject userobj = (from c in _context.Userdataobejct where c.Id == someid select c).Single();
Mainobject.Userdataobject = userobj;
```

If I submit the form to an action like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(Mainobject obj)
...
```

The childobject Userdataobject consists the data, but the id got lost???
The problem is, that if I add the mainobject to the datacontext and save it, the Userdataobject will be created as a new item.

Comment: What `id`? Does your form render a control for `id`?

Comment: the id from the childobject. Loaded the childobject from the database, for example with id 4 (primary key), after submitting the form, the childobject still has its values, but the id is 0. Then if I save the Mainobject back to the database, the childobject will be created as a new entry.

Comment: All you have shown is a model with properties `Name` and `Street`. Post the real code, and the view showing how you generate the input for the `id` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You propably don't have a input for the id in your view, therefor the id won't be transmitted. Use [HiddenFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703631(v=vs.118).aspx) in your form to create a not visible input element that will be transmitted with your form post.

Comment: yes, that was the problem, and I had also to set the EntityState of the child to EntityState.Unchanged. Sometimes It could be so easy,... ;)
Is there a way to encrypt the hidden field, because I don't want to show the id the enduser?